# how to stream or fetch data periodically using bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, clean-architecture

I'm trying to fetch a list of orders for a delivery app. I'm using bloc and clean architecture for system architecture. I'm confused about how should i tackle this approach, whether implementing the logic in the bloc class or the stateful widget. I need to fetch the orders both on the fore and background.
this is my bloc class

```
class OrderBloc extends Bloc<OrderEvent, OrderState> {
  OrderBloc({
    required GetOrders getOrders,
    required UpdateOrderStatus updateOrderStatus,
  })  : _getOrders = getOrders,
        _updateOrderStatus = updateOrderStatus,
        super(const OrderInitial()) {
    on<OrderEvent>((event, emit) {});

    on<GetOrdersEvent>(_getOrdersHandler);
    on<UpdateOrderEvent>(_updateOrderStatusHandler);
  }

  final GetOrders _getOrders;
  final UpdateOrderStatus _updateOrderStatus;

  Future<void> _getOrdersHandler(
    GetOrdersEvent event,
    Emitter<OrderState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(const GettingOrders());
    final result = await _getOrders(
      GetOrdersParams(
        driverId: event.driverId,
        orgId: event.orgId,
      ),
    );

    result.fold(
      (failure) => emit(OrderError(message: failure.errorMessage)),
      (orderList) => emit(OrdersLoaded(orderList)),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _updateOrderStatusHandler(
    UpdateOrderEvent event,
    Emitter<OrderState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(const UpdatingOrderStatus());
    final result = await _updateOrderStatus(
      UpdateOrderParams(
        orgId: event.orgId,
        orderId: event.orderId,
        status: event.status,
        cancelReason: event.cancelReason,
      ),
    );

    result.fold(
      (failure) => emit(OrderError(message: failure.errorMessage)),
      (r) => emit(const OrderStatusUpdated()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want: fetch or stream? These are usually used to refer to two different concepts, which both are asynchronous. The term "fetch" is conventionally used to refer to a on-demand retrieval of data from a service, which a "stream" is is conventionally used to refer to a opening a channel of data which is "sunk" from a service and the data is obtained reactively by listening to that stream

Comment: i think stream is what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a stream, you have two options:

- Listen (subscribe) to events from the orders service in the `OrderBloc`. This implies that on instantiation of a BLoC the subscription is automatically starte.
- Listen (subscribe) to events from the orders service in the `OrderBloc` by using an event `SubscribeToOrdersEvent`. This implies that the subscription has to be explicitly done by adding that event to the BLoC.

For the second approach:

```dart
class OrderBloc extends Bloc<OrderEvent, OrderState> {
  
  final OrderService _service = OrderService.instance;
  StreamSubscription? _subscription;

  OrderBloc() : super(const OrderInitialState()) {
    on<SubscribeToOrdersEvent>(_handlerListenToOrders);
  }

  Future<void> _handlerListenToOrders(
    SubscribeToOrdersEvent event,
    Emitter<OrderState> emit,
  ) async {
    // Cancel the previous subscription.
    _subscription?.cancel();

    _subscription = _service.listenToOrders().listen((orders) {
      emit(OrdersLoadedState(orders));
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```